# Maven version not returning correctly in Eclipse terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-3

I installed maven 3.6.1 on Windows 10 system. I set up environment variables %MAVEN_HOME%  to the installation folder. And also updated the **path** variable with %MAVEN_HOME%\bin. Now in Windows command prompt I am getting correct version of maven when I type "mvn -version" as 3.6.1.

But in Eclipse 2019-06 edition, when I open a terminal view and type "mvn -version", I am getting the message *'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file*.

To verify I looked at Eclipse --> Preferences -->maven --> installations --> EMBEDDED= 3.6.1.

What could be the reason terminal can't return the correct maven version ?

Comment: Why are you trying to run maven from the terminal view? You could add any maven run configuration you need instead: https://www.genuitec.com/docs/assembly/setting-up-maven-launch-configurations/

Comment: How and where did you update the path variable? Did you do it before starting Eclipse?

Comment: @Villat I will look in to this approach.

nitind:
 Both MAVEN_HOME and Path are updated in the PC environment variables.

Comment: @villat: BTW, I am trying to run "mvn -version" to verify the maven version which Eclipse is using or recognizing.